# how to create custom lowercase validator in angular 6 ?

Tags: angular, angular6

i want to create some custom validator on my password filed to check when user input her password. one of those validators is lowercase validator.

**this is custom validator i code that**

---

```
 lowerCaseValidator(control: FormControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null {
    if (control.value === '?=.*[a-z]') {
      return {'lowerCase': true};
    }
    console.log(control.value);
    return null;
```

### }

but it does not work !

Comment: Why would it? `===` is not regex matcher!!

Comment: you can use .match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a custom validators based on regex , check if the value continue on letter as 
lowercase

```
export function lowercaseValidator(c: FormControl) {
  let regex = /[a-z]/g
  if (regex.test(c.value)) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return { lowercase: true }
  }
}
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cr1emq)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the regex that enforces at least 8 character with one uppercase, one lowercase and one number.

```
  ^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{8,}$
```

Comment: Test123456 won't pass

Answer (score 0):

Angular has builting [regex validator](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#pattern). You can use it

Comment: i know but i want use some validator separately. upperCase and lowerCase but not in one pattern . i must use in two different name.

Comment: yep, but for instance lowercase would be something like `Validators.pattern('^[a-z]+$')`

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to make sure that the user enters different cases -both uppercase and lowercase- for the password, and therefore you assume that only lowercase is an error, you could do simply this:

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export function lowerCaseValidator(control: FormControl): { [key: string]: 
boolean } | null {
    const value: string = control.value;

    if (value && value === value.toLowerCase()) {
        return {lowerCase: true};
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can find a working example here: https://angular-ekb1wt.stackblitz.io

If what you want is to make sure that the user has ONLY entered lowercase letters, and no numbers, or symbols, or anything else... then you'd need a RegEx, as other people have already mentioned.